# I can't access images from my containerized jss app but I can access them from outside, from my host (10.2 - with docker)

Tags: jss, docker

I'm rewriting the problem, to put more details.

I set up a jss app in a docker container. It's working fine, even the Experience Editor has already been put to work in this environment.

It turns out that the communication between the jss app container and the CM container is communicating smoothly with the hostname (http://cm). However, when I get it from my browser, it comes with http://cm in the image url, as the GraphQL call is made between the jss app container (nodejs) and the CM container (sitecore). As what comes in the url of the image is http://cm, I can't get it from my computer's browser, because to call the traefic it should be https://cm.maverick-docker.localhost

[image: Networks]

[image: JSS APP on my browser]

How to make the sitecore return the images with the public url of the CM, not with the internal url?

CM:
[image: CM]

JSS APP:
[image: JSS APP]

Comment: Can you please share your docker compose file(s) ?

Comment: yea, would need the docker-compose files. However, the CM might be configured to only talk in https, which you would need to disable for your scenario to work.

Comment: Could you please hostname in docker file what you are providing because in image url hostname is https://cm?

Comment: vincent-lui, mark-cassidy, abhinav-singh

I updated the post, are there any changes that do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I altered the configurations to it don't includes the server url in media urls:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <layoutService>
            <configurations>
                <config name="default">
                    <rendering type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Configuration.DefaultRenderingConfiguration, Sitecore.LayoutService">
                        <renderingContentsResolver type="Sitecore.LayoutService.GraphQL.LayoutService.GraphQLAwareRenderingContentsResolver, Sitecore.LayoutService.GraphQL" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.LayoutService.GraphQL.config">
                            <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
                        </renderingContentsResolver>
                        <renderingContentsResolver type="Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.ContentsResolvers.RenderingContentsResolver, Sitecore.LayoutService">
                            <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
                        </renderingContentsResolver>
                    </rendering>
                </config>
                <config name="sxa-jss">
                    <rendering>
                        <renderingContentsResolver type="Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Presentation.ContentsResolvers.RenderingContentsResolver, Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Presentation">
                            <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
                        </renderingContentsResolver>
                    </rendering>
                </config>
                <config name="jss">
                    <rendering type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Configuration.DefaultRenderingConfiguration, Sitecore.LayoutService">
                        <renderingContentsResolver type="Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.ContentsResolvers.RenderingContentsResolver, Sitecore.LayoutService">
                            <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
                        </renderingContentsResolver>
                    </rendering>
                </config>
            </configurations>
        </layoutService>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```